# MVC3 C# Export to Excel

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, excel-2007

I am trying to export data from database to excel 2007 file.

I just want to change the header of html file to excel 2007 file.

I format the data into a table and change the header to this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= filename.xlsx");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
```

I keep getting the same error:

> "Excel cannot open the file "filename.xlsx' because the file format of
>   file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been
>   corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file"

I also tried this example i found online and i can open in excel 2003 with a warning message, but on 2007 i get the above error message. It need to make it work with excel2007

```
<html 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 11">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
    <x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name>
    <x:WorksheetOptions>
     <x:Selected/>
     <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>
     <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>
     <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>
    </x:WorksheetOptions>
   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
  <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>
  <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>
</x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml><![endif]-->
<style>
<!--table
    {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
    mso-displayed-thousand-separator:" ";}
.xl2
    {
    mso-number-format:M/D/YY;
    border-left:.5pt solid;
    border-top:.5pt solid;
    border-right:.5pt solid;
    border-bottom:.5pt solid;
    }
.xl3
    {
    border-left:.5pt solid;
    border-top:.5pt solid;
    border-right:.5pt solid;
    border-bottom:.5pt solid;
    }
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td class=xl2>17.02.2010</td>
<td class=xl3>4</td>
<td class=xl3>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know this isn't the solution that you are looking for, but recently we supported export to excel from the database by simply creating a tab-delimited text file and saving it in the tmp directory on the server and then returning that text file in the HTTP response.  Excel already supports the parsing of tab- and comma-delimited text files into excel worksheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this form :

```
using(System.IO.MemoryStream ms = /*Include Excel File*/) {
  ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
  ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "private");
  ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ";");
  ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
  ms.WriteTo(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just generating a .csv? Why do you need a full-blown native Excel file?  Another easy option is to just generate HTML content and then set the output content type to excel. Excel will open it and format it, its a quick shortcut, but it works.

Comment: customer require xlsx file and about html option that's what the example above does but it work for xls not xlsx file I get the above error when I try to open the excel file